# Read data from OPC HDA server with Python?

Tags: python, data-science, implementation, opc

I am aware that OPC HDA is an outdated protocol and shouldn't be used if there is any more modern protocol available. Sadly, in this industrial context, it seems there is no real alternative.

I tried to find Python libraries with OPC HDA support without success. So I'm asking here: Is it somehow possible to access data from OPC HDA with Python? If there is no way to directly read the data with Python, is there any workaround possible, like using a third-party tool as a bridge between OPC HDA and Python?

The closest thing I could find are these [OPC HDA loggers](https://integrationobjects.com/sioth-opc/sioth-opc-data-archiving/opc-hda-logger-for-csv/), which connect to an OPC HDA server, and log the data to flat files. That would probably somehow work, but I'm wondering if there is any better solution.

I'm curious for your suggestions, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Best is probably to use an OPC HDA logger as you mentioned. This can be a bit cumbersome to set up, but it will work.

You could try [pyOPC](https://pypi.org/project/PyOPC/). unknown how good that is.